# IndexError: List index out of range (printing integers)

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing

I'm running my definition through a while condition, at the moment I just want it to print all the numbers in the list up until it hits the length of the list.

However, when I build it, I'm getting the error

> "IndexError: list index out of rage"

What am I missing?

```
numList = [5, 2, 21, 8, 20, 36, 1, 11, 13, 4, 17]

def findHighest(intList):
    iIndex = 0
    iValue = intList[iIndex]
    while iIndex != len(intList):
            print(iValue)
            iIndex = iIndex + 1
            iValue = intList[iIndex]

print(findHighest(numList))
```

I get the list printed, but then it compiler error

Comment: You should increment the index only after using it in `intList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is when iIndex is one less than list you are adding 1 to index. For example if your list is size 10 and iIndex is 9 you are adding one to 9 and setting iValue=intList[10] which is out of bounds considering list is 0 based.

```
numList = [5, 2, 21, 8, 20, 36, 1, 11, 13, 4, 17]

def findHighest(intList):
    iIndex = 0
    iValue = intList[iIndex]
    while iIndex != len(intList)-1:
        print(iValue)
        iIndex = iIndex + 1
        iValue = intList[iIndex]

print(findHighest(numList))
```

Comment: But because I've set iIndex to 0 to start with, I'm confused why it wouldn't work up to the !=, surely iIndex would increment up to 9 and then when it is == to 9, it would stop?

Comment: But your while loop condition is size of list which is 10. so basically while loop goes to 9 then increments by 1 which makes the statement iValue = intList[10]

Comment: Right, so it's not checking the last index of 10 with my original code? (Just wanting to make sure my understanding is correct)